# Looking for a better solution setFieldValue() in componentDidMount()

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle, formik

I am implementing a feature update user information by formik. When `componentDidMount` I use `setFieldValue()` to each field but it is not working, and I found settimeout but I felt that some trick. Please give me some a better solution.

[image: My UI]

[image: My code]

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'initialValues' option provided by Formik would be a cleaner solution to your problem.
https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#initialvalues-values

Render the form only when the API call is completed and the data available. Pass the data to Formik as the `initialValues`

```
class FormComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              //some data
            };
          }

       render() {
            return (
            <Formik
              initialValues={this.state}
              onSubmit={onSubmit}
              render={
                ({
             ......
```

Comment: always put helpful content from links in the answer and then provide links for reference.

Comment: can you give me some example, I have no experience formik